# What's the Contentful equivalent of "slices" in Prismic?

Tags: content-management-system, contentful, prismic.io

Does contentful offer a way to create reusable custom components?, I've looked around and it seems they only offer content types which are like entire page templates. In their [article](https://www.contentful.com/blog/2021/04/26/migrating-from-prismic-to-contentful/) on migrating from Prismic to Contentful they mention that [slices](https://prismic.io/feature/dynamic-layout-content-components) are treated as custom types, but you can't use custom types inside custom type, so doesn't seem like a good solution.

I'm basically looking for a way to create custom field groups that I can use across multiple content types.

Answer (score 2):

Contentful DevRel here.

> content types which are like entire page templates

In Contentful content types are whatever you define them to be. An entry of a particular content type can hold page information, but can also hold information about a single component.

[We recommend to structure your content into reusable components](https://www.contentful.com/help/topics-and-assemblies/). This way content stays reusable.

So while Contentful doesn't offer something like Prismics slices you can achieve similar results with Contentful types and a thought through content model.

You could potentially define a gallery content type which in your code is coupled to a gallery components and then reference it from within another entry of e.g. a page content type. This is where the power of content modelling comes into play – you can create a custom content graph tailored to your needs quickly.

As an example, it's really up to your what should be referenced from where. A page can reference galleries, authors or articles, which then can reference other custom entries.

```
page entry -- gallery - iamges
           |_ author
           |_ article - author
```